Vector and raster data converted to WGS84, located wrong or not shown on map
I am currently trying to implement datasets from different data sources in ArcGIS. However, the raster data is in EPSG 4326 and the other two vector datasets are displayed in RD New. I configured the raster dataset with Project Raster to WGS84 and the two vector datasets with Define Projection to WGS84, but now the vector data are not shown anymore and the raster data is still displayed near South Africa. It should be displayed in Europe. The base map is also in WGS84.
What can cause this problem?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You have asked a variant of the most frequently asked Question on this site. The issue was incorrect use of Define Projection (instead of Project). All GIS packages have "reproject on the fly" capability, but if you specify the wrong projection in metadata, it will trust you and plot the data in the wrong place. The fix is to restore the previous projection definition, or define the correct coordinate reference to the dataset.
